# Preventing self closing tags in Soap response

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, tags, jax-ws

I use soap web services using JAX-WS (migrated from Apache Axis2). For some elements if no data available, I am getting self closing tags for which customer's parsing logic expecting empty begin and end tags. I would like to know any possibility to convert self closing tags to empty begin and end tags.

Tried few options not working..

- I tried xslt transforms but tags were removed if not data available.
- Also tried string replace of self closing tag with empty begin and end tags but when building soap message these are changed back to self closing tag by soap XML parser.

Please suggest any possible way to achieve convert self closing tags to empty begin and end tags.

Comment: If the customer's parsing logic can't handle proper XML syntax then in the general case, you're in trouble. They're probably trying to do it with a Perl script written by amateurs. There are probably many other things they can't handle either. Try asking them for a BNF specification of the subset of XML that their parser actually supports. And don't be afraid of telling a customer that they are wrong.

Comment: One solution would be an XSLT transform that inserts the text `§§§§` as the value of every empty element, followed by serialization, followed by a text editor pass that deletes all occurrences of `§§§§`.

Comment: Thanks Michael for responding, we tried convincing customer however they are stubborn and insisting on start and end tags if no data present. For the solution you suggested, are you saying that to include a default value if no data found and remove it later? I tried that, what is happening is when String is passed to construct SOAPMessage from factory class (of JAXWS), somehow parser replacing all empty start/end tags with self closing tags again. You mentioned "text editor", are you referring to string manipulation? Because customer uses some code to parse our XML response.

Comment: Yes, if you want to generate output that conforms to a restricted subset of the XML syntax, then in general you're going to have to use non-XML tools to do it, which is why I suggested doing post-processing with a text editor.